# Jacobian Matrix and Exponential Map?

Tags: lie-groups, jacobian, matrix-exponential, diffeomorphism

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a diffeomorphism.  Can $f$ always be represented as
$$
f(x)=\exp(F(x))x,
$$
where $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to Mat_{n\times n}$?

**Intuition/Direction**
Somehow it seems that $F$ should be related to the Jacobian if this is true but I'm not sure..